# How to fail a cucumber scenario when rails app returns internal server error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, stubby4j

The tech stack that we use for functional tests is *cucumber* with [*stubby4j*](https://stubby4j.com/) for stubbing requests. Sometimes if there is no stub found for a request, rails throws "internal server error" but our functional tests passes in some cases.

**Requirement is:**

When any call made in rails app returns HTTP error code say 500, I want my cucumber scenario to fail. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using Ruby Cucumber? Are your scenarios in-process or @javascript?

Comment: Yes I use Ruby cucumber and my scenarios are not @javascript

Comment: OK, removed selenium tag. Are you tagging your scenarios `@allow-rescue` or setting `ActionController::Base.allow_rescue`?